# 2-D array changes value with var AND let

Tags: javascript

My code currently has a bug where my 2-d array with the bool value false suddenly contains true values before it is assigned any. My current guesses is either console.log somehow is delayed and picks up the values after it is called, with the updated values or that there is some issue that I don't understand about how scope works in javascript.

As seen below console.log(visited[i][j]) results in false for all values but the 
new visited line contains true values even before the following is called.

```js
const field_size = 800;
const cells_in_row = 5;
const frames_per_second = 1;
const cell_size = field_size / cells_in_row;

class Cell {
    constructor(x,y) {
        this.value = 0;  
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.coordinates = [x*cell_size,y*cell_size];
    }

    fill() {
        this.value = 1;
    }
    clear() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

}


const get_new_grid = (random = 0) => {
    const grid = new Array(cells_in_row);
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        grid[i] = new Array(cells_in_row);
        for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i,j);
            v = 0;
            if (random) {
                v = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            } 
            grid[i][j].value = v;
        }
    }
    return grid;
}


const get_islands = (grid) => {
  // bool array to mark visited cells
  let visited = new Array(cells_in_row);
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    visited[i] = new Array(cells_in_row);
    for (let j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {

      visited[i][j] = false;
    }
  }

  console.log("New Visited", visited);
  let count = 0;
  let islands = [];
  let island_coords = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
      if (visited[i][j] == false && grid[i][j].value == 1) {
        // visit all cells in this island and increment island count
        // dfs will return array of coordinates of island
        [visited, island_coords] = dfs(i, j, grid, visited, island_coords);
        console.log(visited);
        islands.push(island_coords);
        count += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return [count, islands];
}


const dfs = (i, j, grid, visited, island_coords) => {
  let row_nbr = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
  let col_nbr = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];

  visited[i][j] = true;
  island_coords.push([i,j]);

  for (let k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
      if (is_safe(i + row_nbr[k], j + col_nbr[k], grid, visited)) {
          console.log("DFSing " + i + "," + j);
          [visited, island_coords] = dfs(i + row_nbr[k], j + col_nbr[k], 
                                         grid, visited, island_coords);
      }
  }

  return [visited, island_coords];
}

const is_safe = (i, j, grid, visited) => {
    return (i >= 0 && i < grid.length &&
            j >= 0 && j < grid.length &&
            !(visited[i][j]) && grid[i][j].value === 1);
}

(function () {
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(arguments[i], undefined, 2) : arguments[i]) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += arguments[i] + '<br />';
        }
      }
    }
})();

window.onload = () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const grid = get_new_grid(random = 0);
    grid[0][0].value = true;
    grid[0][1].value = true;
    grid[1][0].value = true;
    grid[1][1].value = true;
    const islands = get_islands(grid);
    console.log(grid);
    console.log(islands);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <script src="gameoflife.js"></script>
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
So I updated the snippet but it looks like it works on this end, however it shows the behavior I mentioned before on my own browser even with the exact same javascript code and html in the snippet.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit, scroll down and edit above snippet and add relevant examples in a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what I'm missing that I should provide, if you could elaborate further.

Comment: the snippet does not DO anything. Please provide input and expected output

Comment: Objects logged to the console are *live*. If you change them, and *then* expand them in the console, you'll see the *updated* values. If you want to log an object frozen in time, you should create a copy of it - or `JSON.stringify` it.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in the comments by Niet, objects logged to the console are live.